# Ember route not displaying template content

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to Ember and JS, so far the most extensive tutorials I found were using 1.0.0 pre2, but on the official site there is a very nice description and some examples of 1.0.0 pre4. I started to use that. I am stuck at routing, here is my code:

index.html

```
<body>
        Loaded.
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
            In template displaying val: {{name}}

            {{#linkTo "index"}}<img class="logo">{{/linkTo}}

            <nav>
              {{#linkTo "about"}}About{{/linkTo}}
              {{#linkTo "favorites"}}Favorites{{/linkTo}}
            </nav>

        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
            Here comes the about text: {{str}}
        </script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
templateName: 'application'
})

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
name: 'test'
})

App.AboutView = Ember.View.extend({
templateName: 'about'
})

App.AboutController = Ember.Controller.extend({
str: 'my string'
})


App.Router.map(function() {
 this.route("about", { path: "/about" });
 this.route("favorites", { path: "/favs" });
});
```

It's almost identical to the one from the site. What I want and think should happen, is that it will display the content of about template, but instead it just updates the url's to /#/about or  /#/favs . What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I want and think should happen, is that it will display the content of about template, but instead it just updates the url's to /#/about or /#/favs . What am I missing here?

Your application template does not have an `{{outlet}}`. With that in place it will work as expected.

See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/epanan/1/edit) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Though I still do not understand why do I need the `{{outlet}}` . Could you give a site where I can look it up, or a simple explanation?

Comment: Outlet is somewhat like the ```yield``` in Ruby.